# A working query fails If a time range is added in InfluxDB

Tags: time-series, influxdb

This InfluxDB query has no data to return so I am getting back (image below) five `FILL`-ed results, as requested:

```
SELECT mean(value) 
FROM db.autogen.I_MJS_VKM7CU_CNRGXR 
WHERE time > '2019-09-20T14:52:00Z'
GROUP BY time(1s) 
FILL(20) 
LIMIT 5
```

[image: fillled results]

But, if I add a time range to the same query, I get no results, an empty result-set. The `GROUP BY(1s)` seems to not being executed.

```
SELECT mean(value) 
FROM db.autogen.I_MJS_VKM7CU_CNRGXR 
WHERE time > '2019-09-20T14:52:00Z' AND time < '2019-09-20T14:55:10Z'
GROUP BY time(1s) 
FILL(20) 
LIMIT 5
```

[image: no results]

I am a so confused. Did I hit a bug?

Using InfluxDB 1.4 and executing the queries with Chronograf.

Comment: I investigated more in the issue and I found that it fails because there are no points within the requested interval. If I increase the interval to make some point to fall inside, it works. It returns the 5 `FILL`ed results. Shouldn't it work also if no point fall into the given interval?